# Matching if/elseif/else statement with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been writing a regular expression that allows me to match if/elseif/else statements. I've got as far as I have (matching an if/else statement) with help from the Stack Overflow community.

This is the content I'm trying to match:

```
{?if gender = male}You're a guy!{?elseif gender = female}You're a gal!{?else}{#gender|capitalise}{?endif}
```

(The solution I'm aiming for would allow unlimited "elseif" statements, preferably.) It also needs to be able to match the following, to make sure it is backwards compatible:

```
{?if gender = male}Male{?else}Female{?endif}
{?if gender != female}{#gender}{?endif}
```

The output I'm looking for:

```
0: gender = male
1: You're a guy!
2: {?elseif gender = female}You're a gal!
3: {#gender|capitalise}
```

Number 2 should have every elseif in the same string, to allow them to be split and processed after, like:

```
2: {?elseif gender = female}You're a gal!{?elseif this = that}Output (...)
```

My current regex is close, but not good enough.

```
{\?if ([^{}]+)}(.+?)(?:{\?else}(.+?))?{\?endif}
```

I'm still learning Regular Expressions, so I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Not if they're nested.

Comment: This is a little language, and you should not try to parse it with regexps.

Comment: What would you suggest instead of the regexps, @torazaburo? I couldn't find a better way of doing it with my limited skill at JavaScript (and I didn't know where to ask how to, either!)

Comment: Take a look at some parsing tools. For instance, Parsimmon (https://github.com/jneen/parsimmon) is a very painless way to parse little languages. Or, you could use tools such as PEG, which involve writing a grammar in a grammar description language. The problem with regexps is that they're so brittle, hard to maintain and expand, and you very quickly run into a brick wall where you can't do what you want to do anyway.

Comment: It's for a project of mine, @torazaburo, an interactive fiction system. To write decent, customizable stories I use variables, modifiers, if statements and the like, so the stories are just stored in text files. I would quite like a better way to parse everything, currently it is 165 lines of JavaScript, and lots of regex, and it is very slow on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support nested statements, but try this:

```
{\?if ([^{}]+)}(.*?)({\?elseif [^{}]+}.*?)*(?:{\?else}(.+?))?{\?endif}
```

Group 2 will capture an empty string if there are no `{?elseif}` statements.
Group 3 won't exist if there's no `{else}` statement.

[See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/xQ5jR9/1)

Explanation:

```
{\?if // match "{?if " literally
([^{}]+)// capture the condition in group 0
}// match "}"
(.*?)// capture the content of the {if} branch in group 1
(// in group 2,...
   {\?elseif //...capture "{?elseif "...
   [^{}]+//...a condition...
   }//..."}"...
   .*?// and the content of the {elseif} branch...
)*//...as often as possible.
(?:// if possible,...
   {\?else}//...match "{?else}"...
   (.+?)//...and the content of the {else} branch.
)?
{\?endif}// finally, match "{?endif}".
```

Comment: That is close to what I was looking for, but it didn't seem to work right for me - it wasn't able to capture the multiple elseifs correctly if they had the `{#gender|capitalise}` inside them.

Comment: `{?if foo}bar{?elseif cond1}{#gender|capitalise}{?elseif cond2}{#gender|capitalise}{?endif}` correctly captures `{?elseif cond1}{#gender|capitalise}{?elseif cond2}{#gender|capitalise}`. Did you put {#gender|capitalize} as the condition? The pattern doesn't allow curly braces {} inside a condition.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I think I misread it! It's what I was looking for, my mistake. I'll accept your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this qualifies as an "answer", but since you're writing templates, why not use a templating language, of which there are about a thousand. Even if you needed to customize/extend them, that would be easier than writing and maintaining a bunch of spaghetti regexps.

```
{{#if gender = 'male'}}You're a guy!
    {{elsif gender = 'female'}}You're a gal!
    {{else}}{{gender|capitalise}
{{/if}}
```

The above is a made-up template language loosely modeled on handlebars.

If you do not find an existing templating language which meets your needs, or can be easily adapted to do so, the implementations of these engines should provide some inspiration for how to write your parser.

Comment: I've been taking a look at tutorials on parser writing, it actually seems like it would be a very valuable skill, so I'm going to keep writing my own. But I'm definitely going to try to avoid using regular expressions.